# What is the icon between settings and lock-screen in Gnome3?

Tags: gnome3, gui, gnome-shell

I can't figure out what the icon between my settings and lock-screen icon in Gnome3 is supposed to do.

It has two states, locked and unlocked, but it's not the lock screen. When I click it, it toggles its status.

[image]

Comment: Could it be the touchpad? Is there any popup if you hover over it? When is this shown? What is this panel called? Not all of us use gnome.

Comment: which extension are you using to get icons for power-off, lock and settings?

Comment: Nothing, this is just how they used to look like in 2015!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That button locks/unlocks screen orientation on devices that can detect which way they are held - usually touchscreen devices - see [*Screen orientation*](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/Touchscreen) section on the gnome wiki touchscreen page: *Easy ability to temporarily disable and enable auto-rotation (rotation lock)*.

It was introduced a couple of years ago:  [*Add an orientation lock action button*](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-August/msg03729.html). The icon used is `rotation-locked-symbolic` and it's counterpart is `rotation-allowed-symbolic`. They're under `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/scalable/status` and they're both part of the *symbolic icons* set.

---

On some systems with hard disk accelerometers that button appears even if your device doesn't support screen orientation detection. If that's the case you can disable the *gnome-settings-daemon* plugin via `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false
```

Comment: Does disabling gsettings remove that icon from the top right part of the screen?

Comment: @JasonStack - sorry, I don't know... and I cannot test as I got a new laptop  that has no accelerometer/touch screen...

Comment: I also had to blacklist the `hp_accel` module, otherwise the button would come back within a few seconds after system has started.

Comment: This key no longer seems to exist.  I did find org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock=true but the ability to disable orientation changes is gone in Fedora 26.

Comment: @SteeveMcCauley - yep, they've removed the ability to start/stop individual plugins (see [1st attachment here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=772370)) - seems like part of some major overhaul but I have no time to delve into this right now (and as I said above I no longer have the hardware to test it anyway...)