# stop fedora gnome auto-rotate screen when shake laptop?

Tags: fedora, gnome

i've installed fedora 25 today coming from mint !

every things goes great . but when i shake the laptop unintentionally the screen turn around and make a 90deg or 180deg rotate .

every time this happen i have to shake my lap in different position until i get the normal screen !

is there anyway to force fedora to don't detect shakes and laptop moves ?

or to force screen to be normal always ?

Comment: Most likely due to your hdd accelerometer, [try disabling the plugin](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206494).

Comment: @don_crissti thank you ! the correct comment man

Comment: There is also a cryptic button at the bottom of the top right applet (the one for network, Bluetooth, battery status, shutdown, etc) that can lock and unlock auto rotation.

Comment: @Tim 's comment fixes it to.

Answer (score 1):

run  this command as your STANDARD USER, replace cinnamon by the name of the desktop environment you are using (gnome...etc) :

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock  true
```