# How can I get automatic screen rotation with GNOME?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome

I have a Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro laptop that has the capability (in Windows, at least) of detecting the device orientation and ajusting the screen orientation accordingly. I hear recent versions of GNOME allow this. How do I enable it? People tell me I'll see an orientation lock button if GNOME detects that my laptop is capable of automatic screen rotation, but it's not there, even though my laptop is definitely capable.

I'm using Arch Linux, by the way, although I don't think it should really matter very much.

Comment: The OS should auto-detect it... The wiki says the Yoga 2 pro doesn't work:  [No ACPI or keycode signals appear to be emitted for the various screen rotation states.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_IdeaPad_Yoga_2_Pro#Rotation.2FConversion) so maybe yours is the same... FWIW, the plugin is enabled by default in gnome (the devs even [removed the ability to disable it recently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206479/what-is-the-icon-between-settings-and-lock-screen-in-gnome3/206494?noredirect=1#comment709747_206494))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `iio-sensor-proxy`. It has been tested on Yoga 2, and various other Yoga models according to the README.

https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy

Install it, and start it with `systemctl start iio-sensor-proxy`. For me, I only had to start it a few times in the beginning and then it became static and no longer required starting (not sure how, but it did).

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not wrong, `systemctl enable iio-sensor-proxy` instead of `systemctl start iio-sensor-proxy` makes it start on boot.

Comment: iio-sensor-proxy doesn't have the daemon scripts necessary to enable it. It becomes static after a while on its own somehow (I haven't bothered to track down how that happens yet; just glad it does).